# Uploading .JS File To Site Library on SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, issue-tracking

I'm in need of frozen headers in SharePoint Online by request of our management team. I created an "Issue Tracker" via the template and for the most part, they are happy with it. The number one request has been headers that stay in place when we scroll.

I did some searching and STICKYHEADERS for SharePoint came recommended. It says it works with SharePoint Online so I decided to give it a try.

I tried uploading the .js file to the Site Library on SharePoint online and it tells me I do not have permission. I do have the permissions...so I opened a case with Microsoft and they said I can't upload .js files.

So, kind of stuck right now. Is Microsoft correct or is there something I can do?

Thanks...

Comment: Do you mean style library? You are allowed to upload js files to any library.

Comment: Yes, the Style Library. When I try, it takes me to a page that says...Sorry, you don't have access. And provides a form to REQUEST ACCESS. I am the global O365 admin and the creator of this site. 

As mentioned, Microsoft said I am not allowed to but I wasn't all that convinced I had the best rep assigned to my issue.

Comment: You are allowed to. Try creating another library from document library template and upload the file.

Comment: @Brian O365 global admins (and SharePoint Tenant Admins) do not have automatic, unfettered access to any content in SharePoint Online.  They need to be granted access just like any other user.  This is the same as the on-prem versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try steps below:

1. Upload the .js file to a library for example Site Assets:

[image]

2. Reference the js file using Content Editor Web Part in the page:

[image]

3. Result looks like this:
   [image]

Reference:

[Adding sticky/floating headers to a SharePoint list](https://sharepointlibrarian.com/2016/10/06/sticky-floating-list-headers/)

You can regard SharePoint library as a location to store this js file, so you could upload this js file to any library and then reference the file url in the library to your page, it will work as above.

Comment: Do you know how I can get to the Content Editor? I am currently in EDIT mode and it says ADD A WEB PART but can't seem to find the way to access the CONTENT EDITOR.